# How to collect memory dump from meteor/nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, meteor, memory-management, google-chrome-devtools, dump

I'd like to learn to analyze my meteor and node services' performance and memory usage better than just trying to log various thing to console. I've read couple articles about memory management in Node and some baby steps about analyzing the memory dumps with Chrome developer tools.

The question is, how do I get those memory dumps from my apps in the first place?

This memory and performance analysis is done on the server side service. As far as I know, the memory dumps got from Chrome browser are client side memory dumps.

Comment: Note that your application differs in terms of performance a lot in development from production. If you want a realistic view you may create a release build and analyze it in a staging environment using profiling tools that your server's os offers plus Kadira tools if possible.

Comment: What are these Kadira tools?

Comment: you can go to `chrome options -> more tools -> Developer Tools`, it has many tabs like `Memory`, `Performance`. You will get everything required mostly as to see in dev situations.

Comment: @AnkurSoni That only gives you the client side memory usage, right? What I need is the back end nodejs memory dump. I just found node-heapdump package and will try that next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this node package

https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump

can be used to collect heapdumps on server side. Still need to figure out how to properly use it and then time to analyze those dumps.

At the moment I am just writing a single heapdump every time I start my app, but maybe more sophisticated writing method is needed to actually get something done.